# Swipe gesture for touchscreen of phone

Tags: android, actionscript-3, frame, gestures, swipe-gesture

Does anyone know the `AS3` code for swipe and go to the next frame? I'm new to Action Scripting, I'm doing some flash presentation with a loads of slides that doesn't fit on the stage,

So i prefer to put each slide on each frame but i don't know what is the code for this that would animate the same effects as the normal slide does.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention what or how you "animate" the "normal" slide, all I can show you is how to accomplish the swiping:

```
        import flash.ui.Multitouch;
        import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
        import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;

        Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;
        stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);

        function onSwipe(e:TransformGestureEvent):void {
            if (e.offsetX >= 1) {
                //right swipe

                //check to make sure you're not on the last frame
                if(this.currentFrame < this.totalFrames){
                   this.nextFrame();
                }else {
                    this.gotoAndStop(1); //reset to first frame if you want
                }
            }else {
                //left swipe

                //check to make sure your not on the first frame
                if(this.currentFrame > 1){
                    this.prevFrame();
                }
            }
        }
```